# Enforcing a schema on RDD while converting them to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new Apache Spark. I am trying to load a csv file into Spark RDD and DataFrames.

I use RDD to manipulate the data and Dataframe for SQL like operations on the Data Frame.

While converting the RDD into Spark DataFrame I run into a problem. The problem statement is given below.

```
# to load data
dataRDD = sc.textFile(trackfilepath)
# To use it as a csv      
dataRDD = testData.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x)) 
# To load into data frame and capture the schema
dataDF = sqlContext.read.load(trackfilepath, 
                      format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
                      header='true', 
                      inferSchema='true')
schema = dataDF.schema
```

## The Data Looks like

```
print (dataRDD.take(3))
[['Name', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'], ['Joe', '5', '7', '8', '3'], ['Jill', '3', '2', '2', '23']]

print (dataDF.take(3))
[Row(_c0='Name', _c1='f1', _c2='f2', _c3='f3', _c4='f4'), Row(_c0='Joe', _c1='5', _c2='7', _c3='8', _c4='3'), Row(_c0='Jill', _c1='3', _c2='2', _c3='2', _c4='23')]

print schema
StructType(List(StructField(Name,StringType,true),StructField(f1,IntegerType,true),StructField(f2,IntegerType,true),StructField(f3,IntegerType,true),StructField(f4,IntegerType,true)))
```

## Data Manipulation

```
def splitWords(line):
    return ['Jillwa' if item=='Jill' else item for item in line]

dataCleanRDD = dataRDD.map(splitWords)
```

## The Problem:

Now  I am trying to store the manipulated RDD into a DataFrame using the below code and the schema.

```
dataCleanDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataCleanRDD, schema=schema)
```

This gives me the below error:

```
TypeError: IntegerType can not accept object 'f1' in type <class 'str'>
```

The error is due to the mismatch in datatypes of the values in the RDD and schema. The RDD treats every thing as a String and the schema has integer for field1 field2 , and so on. This is a dummy dataset, my real dataset consists of 200 columns and 100,000 rows. therefore its difficult for me to manually change the RDD values to integer.

I was wondering if there is a way to force the schema on the RDD values. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read csv with schema, I would suggest to do something like:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .schema(dataSchema)
            .option("header", "false")
            .option("delimiter", ",")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
            .option("nullValue", "null")
            .load("data.csv")
```

So you will have you data with schema and you can operate on them and instead of map use with column with udf inside it so you always have column name with you.

Also If you have bigger dataset, save it as parquet or ORC format first and then read it again to perform the operation, that will save you a lot of errors and your performance will be very high.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion of "udf" really helped